# Branching promise chains - Separate chains - what happens if I attach more than one then() to a promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

[Several then()s to same promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#description)

> `then()` returns a new promise object. **If you call the `then()` method
> twice on the same promise object** (instead of chaining), then this
> promise object will have two pairs of settlement handlers. All
> handlers attached to the same promise object are always called in the
> order they were added. Moreover, the two promises returned by each
> call of `then()` start **separate chains and do not wait for each
> other's settlement**.

```js
const aPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('Success!');
});
aPromise.then((value) => {
  console.log("then()1.1: " + value);
  return {name: 'jwt'};
})
aPromise.then((value) => {
  console.log("then()1.2: " + value);
  return true;
});
```

1. I am reading the MDN documentation, and I don't know what "*separate chains*" refers to, a example will be great
2. Do the 2 `then()`s methods return different promises?

I just want to try to understand the `then()` method.

Comment: It refers exactly to your second question. The two calls create and return two different promises that have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: So, can we have many chains **arising from** the same promise that are independent of each other? @Bergi

Comment: Yes absolutely!

Comment: Great, this technique of having *separate chains* independent of each other that derive from the same promise is known as "*branching*", right?. I think I've heard that term but I'm not sure I understand it. @Bergi

Comment: Something like "branching promise chains", yes. Notice that "branching" in control flow refers to if-else conditions though.

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, promises are objects that represent the eventual completion or failure of an asynchronous operation and its resulting value. They are typically used to handle asynchronous operations in a more straightforward, linear manner than traditional callbacks.

The `then()` method is used with Promises to schedule actions to be performed when the Promise is fulfilled or rejected. It returns a new Promise, different from the original one, that is resolved or rejected when the given handler is finished.

You can attach more than one `then()` to a Promise. The order and the way you do it changes the execution. Here are a couple of examples.

**Example 1: Chained `then()`**

```js
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000);
});

promise
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result); // 1
    return result * 2;
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result); // 2
    return result * 2;
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result); // 4
    return result * 2;
  });
```

In this example, the `then()` methods are chained one after another. Each `then()` receives the result of the previous one and does something with it.

**Example 2: Separate `then()`**

```js
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000);
});

promise.then(result => {
  console.log(result); // 1
  return result * 2;
});

promise.then(result => {
  console.log(result); // 1
  return result * 3;
});

promise.then(result => {
  console.log(result); // 1
  return result * 4;
});
```

In this example, the `then()` methods are separate and all attached to the original promise. Each `then()` receives the result of the original promise, not the result of the previous `then()` call.

The phrase "separate chains" refers to the separate series of `.then()` calls, as in the second example. Each of these chains operates independently on the original promise's result, and are not affected by the others.

And yes, the `then()` method returns a new Promise each time it's called. This is what enables Promise chaining; the result of one `then()` call (if it returns a value) becomes the input for the next `then()` call in the chain. But when you call `then()` on the same Promise multiple times as in Example 2, each `then()` call creates a new, separate Promise chain.

Comment: I wouldn't say that your second example contains any "chain", since you are only calling `.then()` once in each statement

Comment: I agree with Bergi